# Data change listener on select result with jaybird

Tags: java, listener, firebird, jaybird

Do you know if there is a way to use a data listener on a select query with jaybird.

For example I've got a query like

```
select count (*) from my_table where my_statut='x'
```

the result give me 50.

My application change the field `my_statut` to `'y'` for one row, is there a way to catch the new result with a value/data... change listener in java?

Thanks for your help.

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible via trigger and event api.
Take a look CHAPTER 8 of this manual
http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try this, i think it's exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Once a resultset is created by a query it is fixed and will not change (except for changes made by the program itself to a CONCUR_UPDATABLE resultset), also - depending on the exact transaction configuration - you can't see any changes made in other transactions.

If your application needs to be aware of changes, you could look into the events mechanism provided by Firebird and Jaybird.